# Announcing a pro-tempore election!

Tags: discussion, moderation, election

Literature SE is to have its first [moderator election](https://literature.stackexchange.com/election/1)! Beginning on **13 April**, users may nominate themselves to fill one of the two pro-tempore [moderator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role) slots available.

The timeline is like this:

- The nomination stage will begin on **13 April** - candidates must [nominate themselves here](https://literature.stackexchange.com/election/1). In the meanwhile, users may direct their questions to candidates here on meta (with the [election](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/election) and [discussion](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion) tags), or in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1037/the-reading-room).
- On **April 20**, if there are more than two candidates, the voting stage will begin and last until 28 April. Otherwise, the candidate(s) will be appointed on 20th and the election will be complete.
- In case there is a voting, the results will be announced here on meta on **28 April**.

This election is a part of the experiment/trial with [pro-tempore elections on beta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections) (which Literature still is). The [normal rules for an election](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135360/theres-an-election-going-on-whats-happening-and-how-does-it-work) apply for the most part, except we won't have a formal questionnaire for the candidates (meta and chat will serve for that). Other than that, there are two strict requirements for the candidates:

- A candidate must have at least 300 rep here on Literature.
- A candidate must not have been suspended in the last year.

In order to be able to vote, a user must have at least 150 rep here.

If there are any questions about the process, concerns, or questions for potential moderators, feel free to post them as answers to this post!

Comment: What happens if there only as many candidates as there are slots? Do those people get elected automatically?

Comment: @MattThrower For a pro-tem election like this one, yes. ["Unlike most elections, we won't require pro tempore elections to be competitive. If the number of nominees is less than or equal to the number of open slots, we'll end the election before the voting stage."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314459/278659)

Answer (score 1):

Question for anyone interested in the position:

**If elected, what will you do to help address the issues that led to the vacancies in the first place?** (Which issues should be rather clear from reading through both of the stepping down posts.)

Comment: The two stepping down posts talk about abusive behaviour and intolerant attitudes on Meta SE and among mods. Any candidate can read Meta SE, but to what extent can they make useful statements about moderator-to-moderator communication if they haven't been a mod before? I mean beyond generalities?

Comment: @IkWeetHetOokNiet - Before becoming a mod? Not much. *After* becoming a mod? There's definitely stuff one can do if you've not been already burnt out and exhausted.

Comment: Seeing that this question now has three downvotes, I would like to add that the intent of my first comment was not to invalidate the question, but only to point out that people without previous moderator experience would find it harder to answer without limiting themselves to general statements of intent.

Comment: @Tsundoku Moderator-to-moderator communication was only a very small part of these issues. They were about interactions between Stack Exchange staff and moderators and other users, and among SE staff, as well as Stack Exchange attitudes and policies. I'm disappointed that three of the candidates don't address these issues at all and one says that ze will but does not say how or why this should happen on Stack Exchange rather than on a platform with different governance. This doesn't bode well for the survival of the community.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' I hope we can talk a bit more about this in the chat, later this week.

Comment: @Gilles Three of the candidates are already SE moderators, so one diamond or two wouldn't make any difference to their ability to deal with these issues. This question isn't about *moderating Literature SE* as such. Personally, my attitude ([more details on main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337316/278659)) is to continue caring for the sites I care for but not to waste energy trying to change a company that I have little-to-no leverage over. I want to be here and in tRR participating in this site, not in main meta and TL fighting a losing battle.